# CSS choosing child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My problem is about choosing in CSS first or second image.

```
<div class="ao-preview">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ao-toggle" class="ao-toggle" name="ao-toggle" />
                    <img src="img/local.png"/>
                    <img src="img/local_big.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.ao-item img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input.ao-toggle:checked  +img{
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=99)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=99);
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
        -o-transform: scale(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
}
```

`input.ao-toggle:checked  +img` sets attributes for first image.

So the question is, how can I choose second image in that case? Because I want to make by one click one image disappear and another appear instead of first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic approach could be the use of `nth-of-type` pseudo class

```
.ao-toggle:checked + img:nth-of-type(1) {
     //style for the 1st element here
}
.ao-toggle:checked + img:nth-of-type(2) {
     //style for the 2nd element here
}
```

Comment: I was trying to give you an example. :)

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It matches the nth element of given type. I don't think it enforces a parent-child relation. If it does, then this is an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

`foo + img + img` would be the image after the image after foo.